# Is using ref forwarding to pass functions from one component to another good practice?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I was wondering if this use of refs is good practice. The usecase is a functional component that manages data that integrates with the api of another component and a control panel that needs access to functions on the functional component. The original implementation was to include the control panel in the functional component but for optimization reasons I am trying to separate the two. Are there any reason to not attach functions from a component onto a ref to be used by another component? (example below)

```
const SomeComponent = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  ...
  if(ref){
    ref.updateData = updateData
    ref.deleteData = deleteData
  }
  return <DataRepresentation>
})
const Controls = (props) => {
  return <Controls onClick={props.onClick}>
}
const SharedParent = (props) => {
  dataRef = useRef()
  return <div> 
            <Controls onClick={dataRef.updateData}>
            <SomeComponent ref={dataRef}>
         </div>
         
}
```

I already noticed that if the function requires state info that it seems the function gets passed with the state at the time of update (example below) wondering if there were other caveats

```
[status, setStatus] = useState(false)
updateData = () => {
  setStatus(!status)
}
```

--------becomes--------

```
updateData = () => {
   setStatus(true)
}
```